# Is there an easy way to do automatic resizing regarding HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently learning more about dynamic frontend design using HTML, CSS and JavaScript (jQuery and jQuery UI as libraries). Now I'm already pretty invested and looked for a way to dynamically resize html elements in relation to the current browser window size. I wrote a solution fit for my current HTML myself using CSS changes with JavaScript. My question is, if I can achieve dynamic resizing in a simpler way without manually editing the CSS properties of my HTML elements on every resize.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
       var wWidth = window.innerWidth;
       var wHeight = window.innerHeight;
       var newWidth, newHeight;
       var hFontSize = (wWidth + wHeight) / 75;
       var bFontSize = (wWidth + wHeight) / 165;
       var tFontSize = (wWidth + wHeight) / 184.88;

       if(hFontSize<30){hFontSize=30;}
       $(".headline").css("font-size", (hFontSize+"px"));

       if((wWidth / 1.78) < wHeight){
           newWidth = wWidth / 10.7;
           newHeight = newWidth / 5;
       }else{
           newHeight = wHeight / 31.03;
           newWidth = newHeight * 5;
       }
       if(newWidth<125){newWidth=125;}
       if(newHeight<25){newHeight=25;}
       $(".controlButton").css("max-width", newWidth + "px");
       $(".controlButton").css("max-height", newHeight + "px");
       $(".controlButton").css("min-width", newWidth + "px");
       $(".controlButton").css("min-height", newHeight + "px");

       if(bFontSize<13){bFontSize=13;}
       $(".controlButton").css("font-size", bFontSize + "px");

       $(".table").css("max-height", ((wHeight - 125) + "px"));
       $(".table").css("min-height", ((wHeight - 125) + "px"));

       if(tFontSize<10){tFontSize=10;}
       $(".table").css("font-size", tFontSize + "px");
   });
```

Comment: I would recommend adding your HTML as part of the [mcve]

Comment: CSS can do a lot of this without the need for JS. Look into [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries), [viewport-relative units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units), and functions like [`clamp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp)

Comment: Css based on media queries is common practice.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: The specificity you seem to want and are doing with manual JavaScript (jQuery, looks like actually) may be the only thing that will satisfy your requirements but I think much of what you're doing could be done using the ideas in https://utopia.fyi - the main one being defining a root size in css in a `:root { }` section.

Comment: Thank y'all for the advise! Native CSS functions were new for me, but clamp is especially useful in my current project. Also media queries, the general possibility to make an object viewport-oriented using vW/vH and seamless dynamic design pioneered by the Utopia-project were all very helpful to get a direction for my future developement going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to automatically resize elements with just basic CSS. For instance, here's a script to always keep a `<div>` element the same width as the window, and exactly half of the height, and keep another `<div>` as a square with side length equal to 25% of the window width.

```css
.dynamic {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  border: 0;
}

.square {
  bottom: 0px;
  /*putting it on the bottom for better viewing*/
  position: absolute;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  border: 0;
}


/*I used both % and vw here, % being the % value of the parent element (a div inside a 1000px wide div set to 80% width will be 800px wide), vw refers to the view width, or 100% of the window width. The same for height can be accessed with vh.*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class="dynamic">
    This div should stay the same width as the window and the same height as half of the window.
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    This div will remain 25% of the width of the window, but will maintain the same square aspect ratio
  </div>
```

I believe this should answer your question, but if it does not I will edit my response to the best of my ability.

Comment: Your answer definitly helped me. I'm now using % and vW/vH in my CSS. My javascript has decreased massively.

Comment: Here's a good reference for other CSS units if you need them!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units

Comment: thank you @Isaakfire , im gonna use this alongside W3Schools from now on!